# Automaticaly execute script inside Kuebrentes pod A when i update pod B with ansible

Tags: docker, kubernetes, automation, ansible, devops

I have 2 pods , deploy with ansible :
- POD A
- POD B.

Actually, i execute ansible to update pod B.
When update is finished, i need to execute a command inside pod A.

Do you know the best way to automatise the execution of this script ? via ansible ? kubernetes conf ?

thanks

Comment: “Execute a command inside a pod” isn’t usually a best practice: you’ll almost always have multiple replicas of a pod, and whatever it is you do imperatively will get lost as soon as the pod is deleted and recreated (possibly automatically if a node fails).

Comment: In fact, i need to execute a script for updating database when the version of another pod is update

Comment: Launching a Job to do this is a typical approach (and tools like Helm have specific support for doing this).  Or your pod B could update the database on its own at startup, though you have to protect against every replica trying to do it at the same time and against having different versions of the pod running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is waiting for a pod that I have updated to be ready.

```js
- name: Deploy all cryoserver-ssh manifests
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    src: "{{ item }}"
    kubeconfig: /deployment/ansible-files/admin.conf
    namespace: "default"
  with_fileglob:
    - "/deployment/ansible-helm-deploy/cryoserver-ssh/templates/*"

- name: Remove saml config files into helm chart
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "/project/helm_charts/cryoserver-ssh/{{ item['metadata']['MetadataFile'] }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ metadata_files }}"

- name: Wait till the pods are running
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    kubeconfig: /deployment/ansible-files/admin.conf
    kind: Pod
    label_selectors:
      - "app = cryoserver-ssh"
    wait: yes
    namespace: default
    wait_sleep: 10
    wait_timeout: 360
```

In the second example, I am uploading a script that needs to be run in the pod, making it executable and then executing it.

```js
- name: Copy cryoserver-update-zookeeper.sh local file to remote pod
  kubernetes.core.k8s_cp:
    kubeconfig: /deployment/ansible-files/admin.conf
    namespace: default
    pod: "{{ helm_values['cryoserver']['serviceName'] }}-ssh-0"
    remote_path: "/project/scripts/cryoserver-update-zookeeper.sh"
    local_path: "/project/plays/templates/cryoserver-update-zookeeper.sh"
- name: Run cryoserver-update-zookeeper.sh script
  kubernetes.core.k8s_exec:
    kubeconfig: /deployment/ansible-files/admin.conf
    namespace: default
    pod: "{{ helm_values['cryoserver']['serviceName'] }}-ssh-0"
    command: "chmod +x /project/scripts/cryoserver-update-zookeeper.sh"
- name: Run cryoserver-update-zookeeper.sh script
  kubernetes.core.k8s_exec:
    kubeconfig: /deployment/ansible-files/admin.conf
    namespace: default
    pod: "{{ helm_values['cryoserver']['serviceName'] }}-ssh-0"
    command: "/bin/bash -c '/project/scripts/cryoserver-update-zookeeper.sh'"
```